# WinDbg - execute script on startup

Tags: windbg

I'd like to execute `.logopen /u /t /d` each time I launch WinDbg - so that a logfile will be created automatically, right from the beginning of each session, without me having to specify it explicitly.

Is there a way to specify a certain command / set of commands to be executed upon WinDbg launch?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a shortcut link or batch file which uses the [`/c` command line parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/windbg-command-line-options):

```
WinDbg.exe /c ".logopen /t /u /d"
```