# WinDbg remote kernel debugging - detach from debuggee without terminating WinDbg process

Tags: windows, windbg

When using remote kernel debugging (over network) via WinDbg, executing `.detach` also terminates the debugger itself. To be exact: once I execute `.detach` cmd - the debugger gets detached from the target machine's kernel, then `windbg.exe` process gets terminated.

Is there an alternative to `.detach`, which will allow me to detach from debuggee without terminating my own process? (so I'll be able to go through the command window log, inside WinDbg, after the detachment)

Comment: "WinDbg's own process", then "my own process" - which process? Local or remote?

Comment: @ThomasWeller there's only one WinDbg process - local. I'll specify that in the question.

Comment: Okay, it seems you know only one way of remote debugging, where you have only one instance of WinDbg. There are also other kinds of remote debugging, where you have another WinDbg executable (more precise: an executable from the WinDbg directory like kdsrv.exe or dbgsrv.exe) running on the remote machine. That's why I wasn't sure which process is terminating. IMHO it requires `.endsrv` or `.endpsrv` to terminate that one

Comment: @ThomasWeller You're right; sorry for not being more exact - by "WinDbg" or "WinDbg process" I meant literally `windbg.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

The [WinDbg help about `.detach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-detach--detach-from-process-) does not mention how it behaves for

- live kernel debugging
- direct remote kernel debugging
- remote (kernel) debugging with remote server or remote stub

However, this might be an [XY-issue](https://xyproblem.info/): you don't want to terminate WinDbg, because you want to review your command window content.

An alternative would be that you open a logfile with `.logopen`. This will give you a text file which you can later analyze in any text editor. Thus it does not matter whether WinDbg terminates or not.

Maybe that's why you have [asked this question about `.logopen`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73541308/480982)...

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly why I've asked about `.logopen` :) The reason I've asked this question separately, is to find out if there's an `.detach` alternative which doesn't also terminate `windbg.exe`. But if there's indeed isn't - like you suggested - `.logopen` is the solution. Thanks again!